# Embedded database server engine

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, .net-4.0, embedded-database

I am looking for something that could enable my application (.Net 4.0) to access a locally hosted database without the need for a server.

If this solution supports Entity Framework, that would be the best.

I have already tried Firebird + DDEX, but after countless hours of unsuccessfully trying to set it up as a provider for VS 2010 (Pro), I'm afraid this solution needs to go in the "Unpractical" bin.

Any other proposition ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use SQL Compact Edition 4.0:
http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/2012-editions/compact.aspx

Comment: I thought this version still required some services to be installed on the client's. But if it is completely embedded, I'll choose this as I am a bit tired of playing around with 3rd parties.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use ravendb:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh547101.aspx

or you can use Sqlite:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/236918/Using-SQLite-embedded-database-with-entity-framewo